# React - IE11 - visited links not recognized as visited on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, internet-explorer

I am developing a React application for IE11. Have few anchor tags for links. The problem I am facing is the links do not retain the visited state/css on refresh. The app works fine on Chrome, only on IE the links that user already clicked still show up as unvisited links on application refresh.

Browser - IE11
React - 16.3.2

CSS for visited links:

```
a:visited, a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
  color: #551A8B !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an issue with IE's History API where they are not counting `pushState` calls as visits. Hopefully this would be fixed from IE side.

Quote from the [React Router issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6067) -

> "One possible workaround would be to keep track of all the pages
>   visited from within JS and apply a className with a style matching the
>   visited style. Getting that to work properly will be pretty ugly
>   though."

Links with more details:

- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6067
- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11373805/

Comment: Any possible solution to override this behaviour?

Comment: Sadly, there is only this hacky method: You'll have to keep track of the URLs visited from JS - save it in localStorage / sessionStorage, and to every URL in that list, add a className to everywhere that URL is used in an anchor tag. In the CSS, include this class selector along with your a:visited rules.

Answer (score 1):

```
 a:visited { 
    text-decoration:none; 
    display:inline; margin:0 ;  
    color:red; 
    font-size:11px;  
    font-weight:bold; 
}
 a:focus{
 color:green;
 }
 a:active{
 color:brown;
 }
a:hover { 
    color:yellow;  
}
```

Comment: Tried your sol for easy debugging, however still the visited state is lost on app refresh.